# Ruby "multiply" function strategy

Tags: ruby, rspec, overloading

As part of a test-first ruby curriculum I am following, I need to make a basic multiply method that will at first take 2 arguments and multiply them, but after that rspec tests for the ability to multiply several numbers together in the same method.

I would just like confirmation of my assumption that, since Ruby doesnt support method overloading, I will have to just make my one multiply function accept an array and do the following:

```
def multiply(arr)
    total = 0
    arr.each do |x| total *= x end
    return total
end
```

Can someone provide some enlightenment on the best strategy here? Am I already correct? Here is the rspec:

```
describe "#multiply" do

  it "multiplies two numbers" do
    multiply(3,9).should == 27
    end

  it "multiplies several numbers" do
    multiply([1,2,3,4]).should === 24
    end
end
```

Comment: Not documentation, but I recently visited this resource: [RubyMonk: Methods](http://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/19-ruby-methods/lessons/69-new-lesson). The final section is a calculator that adds and subtracts -- may be useful for you. Basically, you want to look at `*arguments`, where `*` denotes "unknown number of arguments"

Comment: You need to start with `total = 1`

Comment: This creates a method `Object#multiply` (`method(:multiply).owner
 => Object`). Are you sure that's what is being asked? Could it be that you are expected to create an instance method `Array#multiply`? That would be `class Array; def multiply; self.reduce(:*); end; end`. Then `[1,2,3].multiply #=> 6; [1,2,3.2].multiply #=> 6.4`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest would be to do like this as far as implementation of `multiply` is concerned

```
def multiply(*numbers)
    numbers.reduce(:*)
end

p multiply(10,2)
p multiply(10,2,3)
```

Comment: Thanks! I found a good explanation of why this works here: http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-ruby-collections-iii-enumerable-enumerator/